# Studs in concrete

Tags: studs

I have concrete basement walls and I want to install 2x4s studs. Do I need an impact drill or will a concrete bit work? Also what kind of fasteners should I use. I’m 77 so keep this as easy as possible! Lol!

Comment: What you plan to use the studs for might change attachment type.  Putting up drywall compared to hanging heavy stuff from the studs is different.  Are the walls poured concrete or cement blocks?

Comment: Depends a good deal on various things. As a rule a masonry bit in a regular drill may work, slowly, but will be easier/faster in a hammer-drill (which you might rent if this is your only application for it.) "Powder-actuated fasteners" (*e.g.* Ramset) are another option, but can be tricky to get right. Hiring that part of the job out is undoubtedly the "easiest" approach if you can find someone competent to hire it out to.

Comment: We need more detail about what your intended project is.   if you are finishing a basement and just want to hang drywall, you may not need studs and firring strips can be attached to the walls.  They are cheaper and thinner and easily attached with a few concrete screws and construction adhesive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of outstanding questions in the comments that, if answered, would be incorporated into this response.

Generally, to attach wood to concrete, you need to predrill the holes with either a hammer drill (just as an example, Dewalt DCD796) or a rotary hammer (again, example, Bosch 11255VSR). Hammer drills are aptly described as rubbing two poker chips together to create vibrations that will eventually drill a hole in concrete, so you can expect it to take a while. Rotary hammers, on the other hand, have a mechanism that actually creates many hits to break the concrete. In either case, you need a masonry bit to drill with.

The term 'impact drill' is a bit fuzzy (at least for a North American audience): there are impact drivers, which are great for screws but no good for concrete.

Regarding screws, there are many out there designed for attaching wood to concrete. The classic blue Tapcon brand is pretty well understood, and most places carry them. If not, asking for a tapcon will get you what you need. Use the right-sized drill bit and drill to the proscribed depth. If you have a choice, avoid the philips head in favor of the hex head. These are where an impact driver will come in handy, though for many years, people used a regular drill to sink those screws.